# VOLUME_EXTERNAL require API level 29

Tags: android, mediastore

In [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item) they said

> On API <= 28, use VOLUME_EXTERNAL

but this also requires API level 29, and it doesn't save media files into MediaStore.

```
 MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING
 MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH
 MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN
```

also requires API 29, So I feel the doc is not clear, or is there anything I missed?. And how do I save the media files in below Android 10 as well.

Comment: I am blocked in the same part. I am trying to take a photo or select one from the gallery and set as profile but for some reason I am not able to figure out how works this. If you put val collection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
                } else {
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
                } returns the same warning

Answer (score 5):

Even though [`MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#VOLUME_EXTERNAL) was added in API 29, but you are safe to use it as long as you set `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to 29+. I have tested it on API 16 and this constant did not crash my app.

However, if you think this warning is pretty annoying, you can use `MediaStore.<MediaType>.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` instead. It will return the same value as `MediaStore.<MediaType>.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)`.

For instance, `MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` will equal to `MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)`, i.e. `content://media/external/downloads`.

Additionally, you can ignore this warning via `@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")`.

Comment: do you know if this is also true for the DATE_TAKEN and RELATIVE_PATH MediaColumns?

Comment: `MediaStore.<MediaType>.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` is not available for Files MediaType.

Comment: Hey @AkshayKalola, you manage to find and solution for files?